# Write a "Physics GRE" poem!

Tags: discussion

There have been [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212433/should-employees-with-head-injuries-be-allowed-to-post-on-meta) [couple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212781/christmas-hat-haiku) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please) impromptu contests on Meta where one has to write a relevant poem or something. Some have been just for fun, some have been for swag.

Why not have an informal (no prizes, unfortunately) competition on this Meta for some Christmas fun?

The inspiration is [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=12793773#12793773) on the Physics GRE

> the physics one basically just tests whether you've sat through a "modern physics for freshman poets" course

Accuracy of the above statement aside, one can have quite a bit of fun writing physics poems that could find a place in a quiz

The form is:

- The poem must either be a question, or a question+answer
- No restrictions on the specific form of poetry. Preferably rhyming

Have fun!

Comment: (If anyone finds this inappropriate for meta, feel free to vote to close or comment)

Comment: Lovers are good in poetry. So, I should try something hard (doesn't matter if it comes out of compulsion) to show you all that I love Physics :P

Comment: I do think this is inappropriate for meta, but not strongly enough to unilaterally close it. And besides this is a low-traffic site targeted at regulars, so it's not like it's _especially_ harmful.

Comment: So, @DavidZ, would you say that it's [*mostly harmless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless)?

Comment: @DavidZ I don't know what the official policy is. But if there are similar posts in mother meta, where important questions might get lost, why not here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about poetry, and not Physics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

> Why two beams of light are a-racing; 
>     In that way exactly they're facing. 
>     In accord with GR 
>     Once they've traveled quite far 
>     [Will gravity change their true spacing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6197/do-two-beams-of-light-attract-each-other-in-general-theory-of-relativity)

---

> There once was a piece of spaghetti 
>     Quite dry and uncooked and not sweaty. 
>     Too much it was bent; 
>     Away the shards went. 
>     [But why did it break like confetti?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71661/why-does-dry-spaghetti-break-into-three-pieces-as-opposed-to-only-two)

---

> The [universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25328/universe-is-expanding-at-enormous-speed) keeps on [expanding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20056/superluminal-expansion-of-the-early-universe-how-is-this-possible) 
>     And [everyone's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30037/will-acceleration-rate-of-expansion-of-space-become-faster-than-speed-of-light) always [demanding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/is-the-cosmic-horizon-related-to-the-big-bang-event): 
>     Much [faster than light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44386/is-2-5x-speed-of-light-possible-between-two-objects)? 
>     I'm [sure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50061/time-for-light-to-travel-from-most-distant-objects-in-universe) it's not [right](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59803/galaxies-moving-away-at-the-speed-of-light)! 
>     But [where](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60519/can-space-expand-with-unlimited-speed) is my [misunderstanding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90440/how-is-it-possible-the-universe-expanded-faster-than-the-speed-of-light-during-i)?

Comment: Adding links to questions should get you extra points!

Comment: These are beautiful, especially with all those links :D

Answer (score 2):

Just to get this started:

> What is the music that is sung
>    when an electron is far flung?
>
> Why, you idiotic pile of dung, 
>    the answer is bremsstrahlung!

and

> By root of oak and stem of clove where do photons get the shove?
>
> The intriguing answer, by Jove is most certainly Cerenkov

<sup>(Apologies for the cold-blooded murder of meter)</sup>

Comment: And how about giving Wiki links for the definition of certain phrases, like Cerenkov & Bremsstrahlung? Would be easy to find the meaning, for such names given after physicists :)

Comment: The german *u* at the end of Bremsstrah-lung is spoken like the double o in loose and not like an *a* as in lang-uage. @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut: the word Bremsstrahlung isn't a name but literally translates to "breaking rays", as in the radiation which comes from slowing down. Bremsen = to his the breaks. And it's also a [kind of insect](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsen), but this just as a side note.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a brilliant poem, *An Ode to the Unity of Space and Time*, by Shing-Tung Yau, in the standard textbook, *String Theory and M-Theory* by Becker, Becker and Schwarz:

> Time, ah, time,
>
> how you go off like this!
>
> Physical things, a things,
>
> so abundant you are!
>
> The Ruo's waters are three thousand,
>
> how can they not have the same source?
>
> Time and space are one body,
>
> mind and things sustain each other.
>
> Time, o time,
>
> does not time come again?
>
> Heaven, o heaven,
>
> how many are the appearances of heaven!
>
> From ancient days constantly shifting on,
>
> black holes flaring up.
>
> Time and space are one body,
>
> is it without end?
>
> Great indeed
>
> is the riddle of the universe.
>
> Beautiful indeed
>
> is the source of truth.
>
> To quantize space and time
>
> the smartest are nothing.
>
> To measure the Great Universe with a long thin tube,
>
> the learning is vast.

Answer (score 0):

YAY!!! Let's enjoy the last few days of 2013.

How's mine?

> What happens when a sparkler becomes a hurdler?
>
> That's very easy, niggler. It's certainly Doppler..!!!

and this too...

> So, we all sprang out from a bang?
>
> It's not a stupid whizbang. It's the Big Bang!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one...

```
Bright stars out at day?
It must be supernovae!
```

and two...

```
The missing part of decay we know,
is a little bitty neutrino
```

possibly some more coming later.